# List of symbols that do not work in console?

Tags: symbols, command-line

Symbols that do not work in the Wolfram Cloud have a nice "no cloud" icon. Is there something similar for symbols that don't work in the wolfram console? Or perhaps a full list of functions that do work in the console?

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to have these in as a class, property, or property value in the `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` entity.